# Best file type to store a single value in, for multiple access:

Tags: php

I need to take a value from a database and store it in a file on the server, which can be accessed by multiple files, and users.

The data will always be a 2 digit integer value.

My thoughts are .txt, .ini, .xml but I am from far an expert on this, which file type would provide speed, reliability and be easy to dynamically update in php.

Comment: Storing it as xml will "bloat" it by at least 7 or 10 bytes for the containing tag, e.g. `<x>42</x>` or `<x x="42" />`. XML is an utterly useless storage format if it's a simple 2 digit number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all it is, is a single number, there's no reason to use a special file format beyond just plain text (e.g. `txt` or even no extension at all).

Comment: I disagree... a .ini file at least would be legible --> more maintenable in the future, and the performance penalty would be negligible.

Comment: @SJuan76 Um, what? How is an ini file more legible? All it does is add pointless cruft. The filename defines what the value is for; the file content defines what the value is, nothing else is necessary.

Comment: Then next month he can rewrite it to use a different format, but that's no reason to bloat it now. You don't actually know what he's using it for, ever, so making assumptions about how that usage might grow is premature.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean, I was drawn to ini as well but @amber makes a logical point. One additional question though, why is this not writing anything? 

$handle = fopen('test.txt');
$data = "10";
fwrite($handle,$data);
fclose($handle);                    (sorry about the formatting)

Comment: A .ini/.properties file is not that bloat or complicated... at least for me. Had I suggested XML or ASN.1 your worries would be understandable, but `vlabel = value` is not rocket science and most frameworks support it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Simply try `file_put_contents("test.txt", "10");` and make sure you're having write permissions in the **folder** where your script runs.

Comment: That still doesn't return anything, and the permissions are all set to write.